# Future method can not be invoked

Tags: apex, trigger, future, debugging, logging

In the following code the future method is not being invoked.

```
public void setLeadStatus(Account accountObj) {
   String companyName = accountObj.name;
   String accountObjWebs = accountObj.Website;
   List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT company, website, Status__c, IsConverted FROM Lead where company =:companyName AND website =:accountObjWebs];
   List<Lead> updateLeadList = new List<Lead>();

   for(Lead ld :leadList) {
       boolean isLeadConverted = ld.IsConverted;
       System.debug('isLeadConverted ' + isLeadConverted);

       if (!isLeadConverted) {
           ld.Status__c = 'Existing Deal';
           updateLeadList.add(ld);                        
       }    
   }

   myFutureMethod(JSON.serialize(updateLeadList));
   System.debug('myFutureMethod ');

}

@future
public static void myFutureMethod(String strJSON) {
    System.debug('myFutureMethod ');
    update (List<Lead>)JSON.deserialize(strJSON,List<Lead>.Class);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the debug logs? What happens if you comment out the `@future` annotation?

Comment: I don't get any errors in the debug log. Even though I comment out the annotation the future method is not being invoked.

Comment: That's what is in the log

Number of future calls: 0 out of 50

09:15:24.963 (6963262174)|METHOD_EXIT|[82]|01p140000000o0L|AccountHandler.myFutureMethod(String)
09:15:24.963 (6963269487)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[83]
09:15:24.963 (6963288195)|USER_DEBUG|[83]|DEBUG|myFutureMethod

Comment: The METHOD_EXIT for myFutureMethod makes it look like it was called. Try adding a `System.assert(false, 'definitely in this method');` to your myFutureMethod method.

Comment: Indeed in the myFutureMethod seemed to be invoke as I've added the System.assert(false, 'definitely in this method'); and it threw an exception so the method is invoked. However why in the debug log there is no sign of the second System.debug('myFutureMethod '); which is inside the myFutureMethod?

Comment: If it was indeed an `@future` method then it would run asynchronously. When it did run some time in the future it would get a separate log. If your current transaction failed and rolled back it would never run. Maybe try changing your debug message in `myFutureMethod` to something like: `System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'Within the myFutureMethod method');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31689/discussion-between-dylan-d-and-daniel-ballinger).

Comment: N.B. future methods in testmethods don;t execute until `Test.stoptest()` is reached

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion in the comments...

You won't see the logging from a future method in the current transactions log. If the current transaction completes successfully, at some point in the future your method will run asynchronously with it's own separate log.